# Jasmin - component.instance doesn't show component's methods in Angular 8

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, components

From jasmin - calling `component.instance.createNewShape()` returns an error

> component.instance.createNewShape is not a function

`console.log(component.instance)` returns the component but it contains only the properties and not its methods:

```
HomeComponent {selectedShape: 3, selectedMood: 1, allShapes: Array(0), shapeTypes: {…}, moodTypes: {…}, …}
selectedShape: 3
selectedMood: 1
allShapes: []
shapeTypes: {0: "Triangle", 1: "Square", 2: "Rectangle", 3: "Circle", Triangle: 0, Square: 1, Rectangle: 2, Circle: 3}
moodTypes: {0: "Normal", 1: "Happy", 2: "SuperHappy", Normal: 0, Happy: 1, SuperHappy: 2}
test: ""
shapeParams: ShapeParams {}
newShape: Circle {shapeType: 3, corners: 0, moodType: 1}
__proto__: Object
```

Here is the code of the components:

```
import { ShapeType } from './../../models/enums/shape-type.enum';
import { MoodType } from './../../models/enums/mood-type.enum';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseShape } from 'src/app/models/base-shape.model';
import { ShapeFactory } from 'src/app/factories/shape.factory';
import { ShapeParams } from 'src/app/models/shape-params.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {
  public newShape: BaseShape;
  public shapeParams: ShapeParams;
  public selectedShape: ShapeType = ShapeType.Circle;
  public selectedMood: MoodType = MoodType.Happy;
  public allShapes: BaseShape[] = new Array();

  public shapeTypes = ShapeType;
  public moodTypes = MoodType;
  constructor() {
    this.reset();
  }

  public createNewShape(shape: ShapeType, mood: MoodType) {
    this.newShape = ShapeFactory.CreateShape(shape, mood);
  }

  public submitShape() {
    this.newShape.submitParams(this.shapeParams);
    this.allShapes.push(this.newShape);
    this.reset();
  }
  public getTotalArea() {
    let sum = 0;
    this.allShapes.forEach(shape => {
      sum += shape.getArea();
    });
    return sum;
  }
  private reset() {
    this.shapeParams = new ShapeParams();
    this.newShape = ShapeFactory.CreateShape(
      this.selectedShape,
      this.selectedMood
    );
  }
}
```

Why I can't access my methods?
(if you have any questions or recommendation about the question - write them as a comment. Thanks)

Comment: How do you create component, can you add stackblitz ?

Comment: here is the component - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ly6zwa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts